# Prove that the number of admissible $L$-tuples is the $L$'th Fibonnaci number

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I find this exercise in a very old looking number theory book and I've been working on it for awhile. Anyone got any ideas?? Thanks!

---

Fix a length $L$ and consider an $L$-tuple of $a$ and $b$ that obey the following rule:

$Rule:$ If there is a consecutive string of $b$'s in the $L$-tuple, then there must be an even number of $b$ in that consecutive string

---

Non-examples:

For $L=6$ the $6$-tuple $(b,b,b,a,a,a)$ breaks the rule because there are $3$ consecutive $b's$.

For $L=12$, the $12$-tuple $(b,b,b,b,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,a)$ breaks the rule because there are $3$ consecutive $b's$

---

Examples:

For $L=7$, the $7$-tuple $(a,b,b,a,a,a,a)$ is an admissible tuple.

---

Claim: Fixing $L$, the total number of $L$-tuples of $a$'s and $b$'s that obey this rule is the $L$'th fibonnaci number

Bonus: Fixing a length $L$ and natural number $n$, how many admissible $L$ tuples are there where $a$ appears $n$-times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L_n$ be the nunmber of good words of length $n$.

We remark that a good word of length $n$ must either be of the form $aW_1$ or $bbW_2$  where $W_i$ is a good word of length $n-i$.  It follows that $$L_n=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}$$

Checking initial values finishes the proof.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Any insights on how to approach the "bonus question" ?

Comment: Well, you need $L$ and $n$ to have the same parity (else the answer is $0$).  After that,  you have $n+1$ gaps and you have $\frac {L-n}2$ copies of $bb$ to place in them, which is a standard Stars and Bars computation.